# Excel VBA: Looping a macro with custom data from a worksheet with output to another

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a macro that I customize certain parameters of each time I need to run it. To be more efficient I'd like the macro to grab the parameter value from another worksheet I provide and use that value as input for a sub do loop.

Below I provide my basic understanding of what I'd like the macro to do in lay language.

```
Dim row as Range
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim input1 as String
Dim input2 as String
Set worksheet1=Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set worksheet2=Worksheets("Sheet2")
rowCount=worksheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row

For i=2 to worksheet1.rowCount
    Do
        input1=worksheet1.row("A" & i).value (value is continuous text)
        input2=worksheet1.row("B" & i).value (value is integer)
        worksheet2.activate
             Do                 
             *code that relies on the input1 and input2 values to run.
    Next i
End
```

Comment: use range("A" & i) instead of row("A" & i) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro will have code written for it.  Modify the macro's declaration to pass in the variables you want it to use/manipulate.

```
Dim row As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim input1 As String
Dim input2 As String
Set worksheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set worksheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
rowCount = worksheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To worksheet1.rowCount
    Do
        input1 = worksheet1.row("A" & i).Value '(value is continuous text)
        input2 = worksheet1.row("B" & i).Value '(value is integer)
        worksheet2.Activate
             Do
                MacroCode input1, input2
             Next
    Next i
End

Sub MacroCode(input1 As String, input2 As Integer)

End Sub
```